# How to run JaCoCo in other Android Studio sub modules?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, gradle-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I have an Android Studio Project with an app module and several modules as lib (see my settings.gradle):

```groovy
rootProject.name = "MyApp"

include ":app"
include ":lib1"
include ":lib2"
include ":lib3"
```

I run `gradle createAppDebugCoverageReport` which only creates a code coverage report for app level `app` module. Going through the `app\build\reports\coverage\androidTest\app\debug` folders show me only sources in app module were considered.

I tried to apply the jacoco plugin to the lib level build.gradle files - in vain. How can I run JaCoCo for the lib level modules?

Comment: Without further details about your project, it’s not clear how to solve this. Are your library modules traditional Java libraries (→ producing JARs) or Android libraries (→ producing AARs)? Where does the `createAppDebugCoverageReport` task come from, or how have you applied JaCoCo to the `app` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the solution from https://thsaravana.github.io/blog/jacoco-single-coverage-for-multi-module/

In the first step for each module reports were generated and in the second step these reports were merged ino one report.

I was not dependant on other libraries than Jacoco.

Comment: Could you please elaborate or quote the most relevant part of that solution, in case that resource is unreachable or goes offline?