# Caused by groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':lib1' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

To solve my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669322/how-to-run-jacoco-in-other-android-studio-sub-modules): Applying JaCoCo to all Android Studio gradle modules, I applied the solution [here](https://thsaravana.github.io/blog/jacoco-single-coverage-for-multi-module/). This works fine so far for modules with

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}
```

As soon as I add the required `apply from: '../jacoco/modules.gradle'` into a module labeled as a Java library

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
}
```

I get a

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':lib1' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I would like to add the `apply from` to the java library, so that JaCoCo reports were generated for them as well. What am I missin here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have also applied the snippet from the “Improvements” section of [the solution you have linked](https://thsaravana.github.io/blog/jacoco-single-coverage-for-multi-module/) to your `../jacoco/modules.gradle` file? In that case you could replace that snippet with the following:

```groovy
project.afterEvaluate {
    if (project.pluginManager.hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
        android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
            tasks.create(…)
        }
    } else {
        tasks.create(…)
    }
}
```

If that doesn’t solve it, then I’d recommend to run the build with Gradle’s `--stacktrace` option. That should give you more details on where exactly the missing property was found.

Without more information on your exact build setup it’s hard to really say more.

Answer (score 0):

For `Cordova` - some outdated packages cause it - see https://github.com/google/cordova-plugin-browsertab/issues/43 & https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/821, such us `cordova-plugin-browsertab`.

There are multiple ways to solve this, it's even [an example from Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-gradle-properties).

That one working for me - add `cdvMinSdkVersion=21` inside `gradle.properties`. Haven't tried the other ones, but as per [cordova-plugin-browsertab#43 (comment)](https://github.com/google/cordova-plugin-browsertab/issues/43#issuecomment-1145054303), it should work at least with exporting as environmental variable.